# what does app domain mean in google cloud console oauth consent screen verification?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, hosting

I'm trying to get my oauth2 android app verified by the google cloud console so more than 100 users can use it but I'm stuck on this part here:
[image]

What does this mean? Do I need to create a website for this? Is there a way to do it for free?

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, you need a website for this. `Is there a way to do it for free?` Yes for very basic thing but that's another question so maybe creating another post would be a good idea

Comment: **App Domain** means the collection of information related to **your** website on a domain name you control/own.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest that you review [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)  This page is very good and full of a lot of the information you need to know before verifying your application.

## What does this mean?

These links are displayed in your oauth2 consent screen to the user, so that they will be able to find additional information about your application.

[image]

App domain being your website, and the privacy policy being the page on your website where you have hosted your privacy policy.  These two pages are critical to informing your users about your application.  You can expect that google will review them.  While you can have them in your native language it is good to also have a copy in English's so that Google can read it.  I have heard from clients in the beginning at least that google required that they be submitted in English's.

---

[Host a home page for production apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/policy-compliance#host-homepage-production-apps)

> Every production app that uses OAuth 2.0 must have a publicly accessible home page. Potential users of your app might visit the home page to learn more about the features and functionality that the app offers. Existing users might review their list of existing grants and visit your app's home page as a reminder of their continued use of your offering.

> Your application's home page must include a description of the app's functionality, as well as links to a privacy policy and optional terms of service. The home page must exist on a verified domain under your ownership.

---

## Do I need to create a website for this?

Yes, this domain must be registered by you, and must be hosted.  So no there is no way to do this for free that i am aware of.  Domain hosting is not free and neither is domain registration.

## Is there a way to do it for free?

Hosting, Not that i know of.  You should also consider depending upon the scopes your application is using Google may charge your for a security review of your application.  This has to happen yearly.

## Loads of fun links on the same subject.

- [Submit for brand verification](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification)
- [Comply with OAuth 2.0 policies](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/policy-compliance)
- [GOOGLE PRIVACY POLICY](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-US)

Comment: Can I use a hosting service like wordpress.com to host my website. Would that work for this application? Even if it isn't free? Like if I purchase a domain would that fit the requirements that google specifies for app domain?

Comment: No WordPress wont work as the domain needs to be brand verified via search console.  You dont own wordpress.com they do.   read though [brand-verification](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification)

Comment: @ElliotScher You can use WordPress on a domain you own/manage. wordpress.com does support custom domains. https://wordpress.com/support/domains/

Comment: Well thats a new one on me great point @JohnHanley